# Beautify urls in Symphony CMS?

Tags: .htaccess, symphony-cms

I need to Beautify urls in Symphony CMS. I have a list of about 10 searches, static URLs, that looks like this:
http://www.domain.com/#!district=1&region%5Bcity%5D=&region%5Bregion%5D=&type=Butik&size%5Bmin%5D=0&size%5Bmax%5D=2500&string=&sort=1&page=sv%2Flediga-lokaler

The goal is to have them look like this:
http://www.domain.com/stockholm/butiker

What is the fastest way to achieve this? With .htaccess? How would such a rewrite rule look like?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [URL parameters](http://www.getsymphony.com/learn/concepts/view/url-parameters/) in combination with [data source filters](http://www.getsymphony.com/learn/concepts/view/data-source-filters/).

This method may be faster for you than writing a rewrite rule yourself and would avoid any complexity arising from sharing an `.htaccess` with Symphony.